# Extract characters from string based on rule (repeated hyphen)

Tags: r, regex, string, substring, extract

I have a large dataframe with a column that looks something like this:

```
var <- c("150507-001-0000001", "KMD070515-2-0000001", 
"15144KMD01AA-0000001", "Z75Z151222-0000001")
```

What I want to do is extract part of the string. I want all characters undtil **second hyphen**. So this is what I need:

```
150507-001
KMD070515-2 
15144KMD01AA-0000001
Z75Z151222-0000001
```

So I know if I only wanted the data before the hyphen I'd do this:

```
> var <- sub("-.*", "", var)

> var

150507
KMD070515 
15144KMD01AA
Z75Z151222
```

I've also tried a package **qdap** which kinda gave me what I wanted:

```
library("qdap")
var <- beg2char(var, "-", 2)
```

I do get the column I need with the last code, however something seems to be wrong. Because when I do a left_join based on the column it doesn't work. I can find a match by copy-paste in data view, but left_join doesn't find anything. Doing a leftjoin with the var made with sub (see above) do however work. But for some of my rows I need the characters after the first hyphen (and before the second) to find a match.

Comment: And it doesn't help to format as character by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a non regex solution, for those who might be interested:

```
x <- "150507-001-0000001"
paste(strsplit(x, "-")[[1]][1:2], collapse="-")

[1] "150507-001"
```

If you wanted to apply this logic to your entire vector, then use:

```
sapply(var, function(x) paste(strsplit(x, "-")[[1]][1:2], collapse="-"))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` to match the pattern of characters that are not a `-` followed by `-` and another set of characters that are not a `-`, capture as a group (`(...)`) and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub("^([^-]+-[^-]+).*", "\\1", var)
#[1] "150507-001"           "KMD070515-2"         
#[3]  "15144KMD01AA-0000001" "Z75Z151222-0000001"
```

Comment: thank you, this works perfectly! However my left_join is still not working, so guess the problem was another place. I will look into my code.

Comment: @LouiseSørensen  I would check if there are leading/lagging spaces.  Try with `trimws` to remove those